# Firebase or Swift not detecting umlauts

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I found some weirdest thing in `Firebase` Database/Storage. The thing is that I don't know if Firebase or Swift is not detecting umlauts e.g(ä, ö, ü).

I did some easy things with Firebase like upload images to Firebase Storage and then download them into `tableview`. Some of my `.png` files had umlauts in the title for example(`Röda.png`).

So the problem occurs now if I download them. The only time my download `url` is `nil` is if the file name contains the umlauts I was talking about.

So I tried some alternatives like in `HTML` `ö - &ouml;`. But this is not working. Can you guys suggest me something? I can't use `ö - o`, `ü - u` etc.

This is the code when `url` is `nil` when trying to set some values into **Firebase**:

```
FIRStorage.storage().reference()
          .child("\(productImageref!).png")
          .downloadURLWithCompletion({(url, error)in


FIRDatabase.database().reference()
           .child("Snuses").child(productImageref!).child("productUrl")
           .setValue(url!.absoluteString)

let resource = Resource(downloadURL: url!, cacheKey: productImageref)
```

Comment: Did you check to see the URL has been escaped? `Röda.png` should become `R%C3%B6da.png` in a URL path.

Comment: @CodeDifferent the URL path actually in Firebase Storage is `Ro%CC%88da`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horray for Unicode!

The short answer is that no, we're actually not doing anything special here. Basically all we do under the hood is:

```
// This is the list at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/ without the & because query parameters
NSString *const kGCSObjectAllowedCharacterSet = 
    @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~!$'()*+,;=:@";

- (nullable NSString *)GCSEscapedString:(NSString *)string {
  NSCharacterSet *allowedCharacters =
      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:kGCSObjectAllowedCharacterSet];

  return [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:allowedCharacters];
}
```

What blows my mind is that:

```
let str1 = "o\u{308}" // decomposed : latin small letter o + combining diaeresis
let str2 = "\u{f6}"   // precomposed: latin small letter o with diaeresis

print(str1, str2, str1 == str2) // ö ö true
```

returns `true`. In Objective-C (which the Firebase Storage client is built in), it totally shouldn't, as they're two totally different characters (in actuality, the length of `str1` is `2` while the length of `str2` is `1` in Obj-C, while in Swift I assume the answer is `1` for both).

Apple must be normalizing strings before comparison in Swift (probably a reasonable thing to do, since otherwise it leads to bugs like [this](https://twitter.com/asciimike/status/714882427064201220) where strings are "the same" but compare differently). Turns out, this is exactly what they do (see the "Extended Grapheme Clusters" section of their [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)).

So, when you provide two different characters in Swift, they're being propagated to Obj-C as different characters and thus are encoded differently. Not a bug, just one of the many differences between Swift's `String` type and Obj-C's `NSString` type. When in doubt, choose a canonical representation you expect and stick with it, but as a library developer, it's very hard for us to choose that representation for you.

Thus, when naming files that contain Unicode characters, make sure to pick a standard representation (C,D,KC, or KD) and always use it when creating references.

```
let imageName = "smorgasbörd.jpg"
let path = "images/\(imageName)"
let decomposedPath = path.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping // Unicode Form D
let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child(decomposedPath)
// use this ref and you'll always get the same objects
```

Comment: So what are my options? As I understand there is no point to do the same again like "Code Different" answered since you are doing it already "Under your hood".

Comment: Your option is to pick one Unicode normalization (I edited my answer to show D), and stick to it for all operations. Swift and Objective-C handle things differently, so it matters which one you use. Copying and pasting random Unicode characters probably won't work, since they'll be treated differently (most likely).

Comment: Thank you so much :) So much messing but it is working now perfectly.

Comment: I just gotta say that it is not the end of the problem. With the decomposed path, those are the only images that are not caching. Thus I think I just gotta remove those.

Answer (score 3):

After spending a fair bit of time research your problem, the difference boils down to how the character `ö` is encoded and I traced it down to Unicode normalization forms.

The letter `ö` can be written in two ways, and `String` / `NSString` considers them equal:

```
let str1 = "o\u{308}" // decomposed : latin small letter o + combining diaeresis
let str2 = "\u{f6}"   // precomposed: latin small letter o with diaeresis

print(str1, str2, str1 == str2) // ö ö true
```

But when you percent-encode them, they produce different results:

```
print(str1.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())!)
print(str2.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet())!)

// o%CC%88
// %C3%B6
```

My guess is that Google / Firebase chooses the decomposed form while Apple prefers the other in its text input system. You can convert the file name to its decomposed form to match Firebase:

```
let str3 = str2.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping
print(str3.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLPathAllowedCharacterSet()))

// o%CC%88
```

This is irrelevant for ASCII-ranged characters. Unicode can be very confusing.

References:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (highly recommended)
- [Strings in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30)
- [NSString and Unicode](https://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/unicode/)