# Android or Firebase not detecting í á

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm getting this problem when i try to download pdf file from firebase, I think that Firebase or Android is not detecting accented characters e.g. (í, á) but it doesn;t happen with ó, only with the others.

I did some easy things with Firebase, I downloaded pdf files from my bucket, I have in Realtime Database some data like Paráclesis.pdf a reference data to get from firebaseStorage my file something like this:

mybucket/Paráclesis.pdf

so the problem occurs if I try to download a file with í,á (with ó it doesn't happen). I get this error:

com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: Object does not exist at location

I tried to use:

```
URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8"); //nothing i get the same 

try {
        byte[] utf8Bytes = fileName.getBytes("UTF-8");

        fileName = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");
        Log.d(TAG_DEBUG, "fileName "+ fileName);

    }
```

and othes methods trying encode my fileName or anything that may help me but I always get the same error

I see this link but it's for ios

[ioslink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39026304/firebase-or-swift-not-detecting-umlauts)

in ios works with this code

```
           self.storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("\(self.selectedOpciones_name)/\(self.selectedHeaderOpciones)")

            let decomposedPath = ("\(self.selectedPDFTitle).pdf").decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping // Unicode Form D

            self.storageRef.child(decomposedPath).downloadURLWithCompletion{ (URL, error)
```

but in android i dont know how can i doing this

```
Normalizer
            .normalize(fileName, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
```

(NSString *)decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping
Equivalent to NFD in Java/Android

Comment: Having the same issue, did you ever get it resolved?